# How insert XML tag value into variable using XMLTABLE in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Getting Error :- 
    01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
    *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE 

   p_tranxml     VARCHAR2(4000);

   p_test        VARCHAR2(4000);   

BEGIN


 p_tranxml := '<TRANSACTIONS>
                  <TRANRECORD>
                      <SYSTRNNO>50100000000250000031</SYSTRNNO>
                  </TRANRECORD>
                  <TRANRECORD>
                      <SYSTRNNO>50100000000250000032</SYSTRNNO>
                    </TRANRECORD>
             </TRANSACTIONS>';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_tranxml);  



 SELECT NAME 
 INTO p_test
FROM XMLTABLE('/TRANSACTIONS/TRANRECORD'  
         PASSING   
            XMLTYPE(p_tranxml)
         COLUMNS  
            --describe columns and path to them:  
            NAME  varchar2(20)    PATH './SYSTRNNO'
     ) xmlt  ;  

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_test);

END;
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL and SQL-Server tags, your question having nothing to do with them.

Comment: Your query returns 2 records `50100000000250000031` and `50100000000250000032`. However `select ... into ...` must return only 1 record.

Comment: Thank's for prompt reply it's work. but i want both record so how could i get both record.